# I have to do a project building DC voltmeter, ammeter and AC voltmeter. It has restricted spec which is really hard to understand for me as a beginner

Tags: meter

[image]

I am not an English native also I am new with these things. I figured out how to make meter but I just do not understand what they want us to do with these restricted part. It would be really nice if someone become specific about this and help me to understand.

My meter have to measure 1mA-5mA and for voltage 5 to 20V

Comment: The part is the meter you must use. Also we don't know about why your course has to use it so why not ask the advisor?

Comment: The old black Simpson meters from the 70's were like the must-have instrument for engineers.  You ought to see what you can dig up on their design.

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: NO no. I just want to understand what does it mean. Is it talking about a meter that the specific requirement or we have to make a meter that the specific requirement.

Comment: Asking your advisor is key.

Answer (score 4):

The meter they specify is a component which you must use.

In other words, your circuit must deliver 1.0 mA at full-scale input to a load (the meter coil) with a resistance of 130Ω (+/-10%, though that won't matter until you start to consider calibration and accuracy, so maybe ignore it for now).

The full-scale input will be either 5mA or 20V depending on whether it is measuring current or voltage.

Comment: I agree. The word "restricted" here just means that you may NOT choose to use some other part instead in your design. It means you are restricted (prevented) from simplifying the problem by just deciding to use another part to make your design easier.

Comment: is the 1mA is the meter current? If the resistance is 130 ohm then the voltage I need is = (130 * 0.001) = .130V for the following meter right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can think of the meter coil as a simple (floating) resistor and you can connect it in whatever circuit you need.

Comment: How could be I sure that the coil bears the measurement?

Comment: That's what [meters](https://i.imgur.com/ELjy01w.png) do. You put (in this case) 1mA through the 130Ω  and the meter swings to full scale (1mA). You put 0mA through the coil and the meter goes back to zero.

Comment: A 1000 ohm resistor will carry 1mA when a 1V signal is applied. So a 1mA meter movement is sometimes referred to as being 1000 ohms per volt. This should give you a clue about the resistor needed for the 5V and 20V DC designs. You could also look at the schematic for the Simpson 260, but it is 20,000 ohms per volt. http://simpson260.com/downloads/simpson_260-8xi_schematic.pdf

Comment: Thank you Sphero I get this part. I am just wonder since we have to have 130 ohm for the meter. Since we are using coil for the resistance, how could be I am sure that I have inserted 130 ohms of resistance there? is it by measuring by another digital multimeter for the resistor?

Comment: The 130 ohms is a given. It’s a characteristic of the meter. You just have to figure out what to put (for example) in series with it to get the desired behavior.

Comment: oh I got it. Basically I have to get the actual part to build it. Therefore, I am expecting to get that thing from the institution right?

Comment: Yes, but in the meantime they will give you a 130 ohm resistor in place of the meter so you won’t ruin a real meter by, say, putting 5V across it.

Comment: I get it. Its clear now. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to solve two tasks:

- to coarsen the sensitivity (to enlarge the range) of the available 1 mA ammeter to 5 mA
- to convert the available 1 mA ammeter into a 20 V voltmeter

You can solve the first task using the "current divider" device by connecting a resistor ("shunt") in parallel with the ammeter.

You can solve the second task using the "voltage divider" device by including a ("ballast") resistor in series with the ammeter.

---

BTW this technique of converting an ammeter to a voltmeter was used in the 19th and maybe until the middle of the 20th century because back then they didn't have voltmeters, only ammeters.

Now we have very good voltmeters (ADCs) and so we use the reverse technique to convert a voltmeter into an ammeter - by connecting a resistor ("current-to-voltage converter") in parallel to the voltmeter.

See also my two stories in [Circuit Idea](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea) wikibook:

[Passive Voltage-to-Current Converter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Passive_Voltage-to-Current_Converter)

[Passive Current-to-Voltage Converter](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Passive_Current-to-Voltage_Converter)

Comment: Your last part give me a great idea to think about. Thank you  so much!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. I will check them out.